# Programmatically know if a control (or empty cell) is merged in Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm working with MS Access VBA, an I have an stacked design in a form (the yellow grid).
it's possible to know (programmatically) if a control (or empty cell) is in merged cell or not?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Sure!. Done!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are not cells, these are controls (labels, textboxes, comboboxes, etc). Controls are not merged. What you see is a grouped layout. Controls  are associated as a group and controls will move together if you grab and drag the box in upper left. Resize width of one control and you resize all in same "column"; resize height and you resize all in same "row". Forms and reports built by Access wizards default to grouped layout. To remove grouping: **select a group > right click > Layout > Remove layout**.

To determine the layout type of a control, reference its Layout property.

`Me.controlname.Layout`
0 = not grouped
1 = tabular
2 = stacked